# How can I use the same file created in the code?

Tags: list, file, numpy, file-writing

I have created a file as:

```
fd = open("output.txt",'w')
fd.write("*TITLE")
fd.write('\n')
fd.write("*Look below")
fd.write('\n')
```

And, I want to write more into this file with the following command:

```
temp = [(1,2),(3,4),(a,b)]
np.savetxt("output.txt", temp , fmt="%d", comments='')
fd.close()
```

However, when I open the output.txt file, it only has `"b"` and nothing more.

How can I fix it or do you know where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the open file to the NumPy output function:

```
np.savetxt(fd, temp , fmt="%d", comments='')
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), the first argument is a filename or file handle.

Comment: I have tried but it raises two errors:  % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int64') and format specifier ('%d %d') and TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: @podedo: For the second error you just need to open your file in binary mode: `fd = open("output.txt",'wb')`.  For the first, I think the error message is extremely clear and you can figure it out.